# Postgres: It is possibile cast a bytea type (pdf) in text or serach in?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pdf, casting

I have a PostgreSQL table with a bytea that is a PDF.

I want to search a text in. How it is possible?
Is there a possibility to cast pdf to text directly in sql-query?

Comment: No, that's not possible. SQL knows nothing about the structure of a PDF document.

Comment: You could probably pass the `bytea` to a [PL/Python](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython.html) function, and extract the text with some external library.